# Ajax response contains a value, but does not equal the value?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an Ajax get request using Jquery, which on the server side has no special headers, and so just returns text/html.

```
   $.get("index.php?action=get_current_page", function (response) {
```

when I then do an alert:

```
   alert(response);
```

the value shows: inbox

But why then does this on the very next line evaluates to false:

```
if (response == "inbox") {
```

Any ideas? Do you need more info? Thanks.

The whole snippet is:

```
 $.get("index.php?action=get_current_page", function (response) {
       alert(response);

       if (response == "inbox") {
           alert("hello");
           loadInbox();
       }
```

And on the server side I am simpyl echoing a session variable:

```
echo $_SESSION['current_page'];
```

Comment: You're going to need to show the whole response.

Comment: "The very next line" inside the function? Or the next line after `$.get()`? Is `response.length` equal to 5 (or is there some whitespace at the end or something)?

Comment: inbox without quotes is the whole response, do i have to use json, I thought I could jus use html in this case

Comment: What does `alert(response.length)` show you?

Comment: You don't have to use JSON. Please double check the length with client-side code (as per Felix's comment) rather than assuming what you set on the server-side will pass on through as expected.

Comment: Yikes response.length is 11

Comment: Did you try String(response) == "inbox".. just a guess :)

Comment: That means there is some invisible chars ( most likely spaces )

Comment: There you go :) Fix your server side script. Or if you simply want to test whether the response *contains* the string "inbox", use `repsonse.indexOf('inbox') > -1`.

Comment: Felix yours is the only one that works. But it seems like a tacky solution. I assume there must be some hidden new line characters or something beign returned with the html. I should probably just stick with json anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It most likely contains spaces or other invisible chars. If don't have control of server side output, then you can use JavaScript to replace invisible characters. Otherwise, if you do have control of server side output. You can do this on the server side.

If you have server-side access to the PHP script, then [`trim()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) will do the job of replacing white space from the beginning and end of the string.

```
$response = trim($response);
echo $response;
```

If you only have access to the client side then use JavaScript. More specifically,  [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) will get the job done by replacing every occurrence of characters that are not `a-z` or `A-Z`

```
response = response.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g,'');
```